# How to create a Slanted wall with Revit API?

Tags: python, revit-api

Im trying to develop script for myself in dynamo(Revit 2021), but I don't understand how can I create the slanted wall?
According to this [blog of changes in revit 2021,](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2020/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2021-api.html#4.1.9) there are such parameters for creating inclined walls as BuiltInParameter.WALL_CROSS_SECTION. However, there are no examples of using them to existing parameters or classes. Therefore, I do not understand exactly where to use it at the stage of creating a line or wall and what should be the appeal?

The part of the code where the wall itself is created, in the end I tried to turn to the wall and change its orientation parameter to an inclined one, because there are no other appeals.

```
import sys
import clr
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *

clr.AddReference('RevitServices')
import RevitServices
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
from RevitServices.Transactions import TransactionManager
doc = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument

clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
import Autodesk
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *

clr.AddReference('RevitNodes')
import Revit
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.Elements)
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.GeometryConversion) 
# points for line
p_tp_1_1 =  XYZ(x_tp_1_1, y_tp1, levels.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.LEVEL_ELEV).AsDouble() + size_of_batten_1v_width)
p_tp_1_2 =  XYZ(x_tp_1_2, y_tp1, levels.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.LEVEL_ELEV).AsDouble() + size_of_batten_1v_width)
# Draw a line
wall_line_tp1 = Line.CreateBound(p_tp_1_1, p_tp_1_2)
# Create a Wall
wall_tp1 = Wall.Create(doc, wall_line_tp1, type.Id, levels.Id, h_tp_1, z_tp1, 0, 1)
wall_tp1.Orientation(BuiltInParameter.WALL_CROSS_SECTION(1))
```

If there is anyone who has encountered this, the example can be in C++ or c#, I will try to adapt it in python.
And thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out on my own. If anybody have the same question, there is a cod:

```
# Points
p_tp_1_1 =  XYZ(x_tp_1_1, y_tp1, levels.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.LEVEL_ELEV).AsDouble() + size_of_batten_1v_width)
p_tp_1_2 =  XYZ(x_tp_1_2, y_tp1, levels.get_Parameter(BuiltInParameter.LEVEL_ELEV).AsDouble() + size_of_batten_1v_width)
# Draw a line
wall_line_tp1 = Line.CreateBound(p_tp_1_1, p_tp_1_2)
# Create a Wall
wall_tp1 = Wall.Create(doc, wall_line_tp1, type.Id, levels.Id, h_tp_1, z_tp1, 0, 1)
# Here we get the parameter of the wall
cross_wall = Wall.get_Parameter(wall_tp1, BuiltInParameter.WALL_CROSS_SECTION)
# Set a value to the parameter ( 0 - slanted; 1 - vertical)
cross_wall.Set(0)
# assign the angle of the wall
angle_wall.get_Parameter(wall_tp1, BuiltInParameter.WALL_SINGLE_SLANT_ANGLE_FROM_VERTICAL)
# For example, we tilt it by 30 degrees: 
angle_wall.Set(0.30)
```

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my answer to [your question in The Revit API discussion forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/how-to-create-a-slanted-wall-with-revit-api-python/td-p/11166651), here are some API samples and updates from The Building Coder that may be of use:

- [The FaceWall Class and Slanted Walls](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/03/the-facewall-class-and-slanted-walls.html)
- [Create FaceWall on Slanted Mass Face](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/01/create-facewall-on-slanted-mass-face.html)
- [What's New in the Revit 2021 API: 1.9. Slanted Walls](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2020/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2021-api.html#4.1.9)
- [What's New in the Revit 2022 API: 2.1.4. Slanted and Tapered Walls](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2021/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2022-api.html#4.2.1.4)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I've already seen this links before. The first link have the cod from 2011s and this is not using new opportunities in Revit 2021(the third link). So that's why I ask an example how to use the "BuiltinParameter", rather his methods like WALL_CROSS_SECTION and WALL_SINGLE_SLANT_ANGLE_FROM_VERTICAL. I don't understand what class they apply to(like walls or mb face wall). From the second link I understand this methods apply to face wall or not? If you give an exemple of using this (even c++ or c#) I will really appreciate you.